# How to assign task to other users using exchange service?

Tags: c#, exchange-server

I am trying to create a task using exchange service c#. I able to create the task, but how I can assign to other users. My sample code is below

```
Task tsk = new Task(serviceData);
tsk.Subject = "Test Subject Using Exchange Service-111";
tsk.Save();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, EWS doesn't support assigning tasks to other users.